# When using 'Export collections to bigquery' firebase extension, some documents are not available in the raw_changelog table

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

We are using **Export collections to bigquery** firebase extension to export collections from Firestore to BigQuery. Everything is working fine except some documents are missing from the raw_changelog table. We could not find anything related to the missing documents in the logs either.

How can we identify using the logs that a particular document has not been exported to BigQuery? How to backfill the missing documents in the `raw_changelog` table once they are identified?

**Note** : *This extension needs to be used for exporting data related to financial transactions. So, it needs to be reliable. Even a single missing document is problematic.*